# Select unique element values based on the attribute with XPath 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, unique

I have an XML file that stores movies and their actors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="index.xsl"?>
<movies
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="movies.xsd">

<movie movieID="1">
    <actors>
        <actor actorID="1"> 
            <name link="hello">Bob</name>
        </actor>

        <actor actorID="2"> 
            <name link="hello">Mike</name> 
        </actor>
    </actors>   
</movie>

<movie movieID="2">
    <actors>
        <actor actorID="1"> 
            <name link="hello">Bob</name>
        </actor>

        <actor actorID="2"> 
            <name>Daniel</name>
        </actor>
    </actors>   
</movie>

</movies>
```

As you can see from the code above, I have 2 "movie" elements that contain 2 "actor" child elements each. 
3 out of 4 "name" child elements contain an attribute "link": Bob, Mike, Bob

I'm using the following XSLT code to display only the names of the actors that contain an attribute "link":

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>Actors: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/movies/movie/actors/actor/name[@link]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name[@link]">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:element name="br" />
</xsl:template>
```

The output that I get:

```
Bob
Mike
Bob
```

As you can see the name "Bob" repeats twice. I want to display only unique actor names that have an attribute "link"

I have tried the following XPath 1.0 queries:

```
<xsl:template match="[not(@name[@link] = preceding::@name)]">

<xsl:template match="not(@name[@link] = preceding::@name)">

<xsl:template match="not(@name[@link] = preceding-sibling::@name)">
```

All of them made the page display an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The efficient way to do grouping like this in XSLT 1.0 is to use Muenchian grouping (I've added a `div` and a `br` for clarity; feel free to remove them):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="kName" match="actor/name[@link]" use="." />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <div>
      <xsl:text>Actors: </xsl:text>
      <br />
      <xsl:variable name="actorNames" 
                    select="/movies/movie/actors/actor/name[@link]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates 
                    select="$actorNames[generate-id() = 
                                        generate-id(key('kName', .)[1])]" />
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <br />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

```
<div>
  Actors: <br />Bob<br />Mike<br />
</div>
```

Comment: That's perfect. It's good to know a more efficient way of defining a unique element. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

another way to do it in **XSLT1.0** for small XML sources:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>Actors: </xsl:text>   
    <xsl:for-each select="/movies/movie/actors/actor/name[@link and not(. = preceding::*)]">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <br/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Output:

```
Actors: Bob<br/>Mike<br/>
```

Comment: It may seem more simple to you, but is very inefficient. That's why Muenchian grouping was developed: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: @michael.hor257k : got the point from above link. "it involves two XPaths that take a lot of processing for big XML sources (such as those from big databases)". But it can be treated as an alternate solution which can be used for small sources.

Comment: I strongly recommend using Muenchian grouping every time. Its not that complicated that a simpler alternative is required - and it saves to need to rewrite when the source grows (as it often does).