# XSLT sort element doesn't work

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I am trying to sort all the actor names displayed in a list. There must be something simple that I'm missing but I just can't figure out what it is.

```
    <xsl:key name="kName" match="actor/name" use="." />

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="html">
        <xsl:element name="head">
            <xsl:element name="title">
                <xsl:text>Actors list</xsl:text>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="h2">Actors list</xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="body">
            <xsl:variable name="actorNames" select="/movies/movie/cast/actors/actor/name"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$actorNames[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kName', .)[1])]">
                <xsl:sort select="./name"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name">
      <xsl:element name="a">
          <xsl:attribute name="href">actor_details.php?movieID=<xsl:value-of select="../../../../@movieID"/>&amp;actorID=<xsl:value-of select="../@actorID"/></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="br" />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an xsl:key for sorting, you can apply the [sort](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N6461.html#d9253e19) in the apply-templates directly.

This works:

```
 <xsl:key name="kName" match="actor/name" use="." />

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="html">
      <xsl:element name="head">
        <xsl:element name="title">
          <xsl:text>Actors list</xsl:text>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="h2">Actors list</xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="body">

        <!-- your way -->
        <xsl:variable name="actorNames" select="/movies/movie/cast/actors/actor/name"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$actorNames[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kName', .)[1])]">
           <xsl:sort select="."/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

        <!-- my way -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="movies/movie/cast/actors/actor">
          <xsl:sort select="./name"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, rene. But how would I apply it in my particular case, since I'm using "apply-templates select="$actorNames[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kName', .)[1])]" ? I've updated my post with your solution but it still doesn't work for some reason

Comment: I added also an option for your way of implementing that works

Answer (score 1):

What you were actually doing wrong was this. Your apply-templates was selecting name elements. Your xsl:sort key was ./name, which is evaluated relative to the nodes being sorted. As name elements do not have a name child, this was selecting nothing.

But as rene pointed out, your use of keys is also quite unnecessary.

Comment: thank you for clarifying this, Michael. I was using keys to select unique elements values as I've posted in my other question. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455618/select-unique-element-values-based-on-the-attribute-with-xpath-1-0). So I had to use keys but I also wanted to sort these unique element values as well.